# Reading in multiple xlsx files to separate data frames

Tags: r, purrr, readxl

Looking for a way to read in multiple xlsx files from a folder at one time in a way that loads each individual sheet in each file into a separate data frame. Most solutions I've found such as purrr::map_df/purrr::map_dfr seem to be geared towards stitching them together into one df at once.

For context: while I do intend to eventually stitch these files together into one df, there's a fair amount of munging specific to each tab needed first before doing so.

Comment: We will need double lapply, one to loop through files, then one to loop through sheets. Something like: `lapply(list.files..., find out number of sheets, lapply(sheetn, readxl nth sheet))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` in place of `lapply` if you want to use `purrr`:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "^.*\\.xlsx$")

dfs <- lapply(files, 
              \(x) {
                sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(x)
                output <- lapply(sheets, 
                                 \(y) readxl::read_xlsx(x, sheet = y))
                setNames(output, sheets)
              })
```